# Spark: Type Conversion in DataFrame

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark-sql, mysql-connector

I have a field in dataframe which is of type string. I am using the overwrite mode for saving to mysql.  The string field is getting saved as text field in the mysql. I want to save it as varchar (40).

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(mysqlUrl,tableName,properties)
```

How can i achieve the same?

And also is it possible to apply the indexes in dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the cast function to convert the data types in data frame before writing to the database.

```
df.selectExpr(cast(column name) as int)  fromid).write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(mysqlUrl,tableName,properties)
```

indexes can be applied using windowing functions.

Comment: this not work for string type to varchar type